# Automatic down-votes from spam flags are not removed when the flags are declined

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, declined-flags, automatic-votes

I found two spam flags on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161545/drupal-shop-gives-whitepage-on-login (now automatically deleted) which were raised just because the question contained a link to a Drupal site the OP is working on.

I declined them as it was not spam, and another moderator on Drupal Answer (Clive) noticed that the question clearly reports two down-votes, but the [user reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/48388/ivan-veselinov-nedelchev?tab=reputation) shows more down-votes; in fact, it seem to still include the automatic down-votes.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

I would expect the automatic down-votes to be removed, once the spam flags are declined. The code handling the question's score seems to think so too, but the code handling the reputation seems to think different.

There aren't [other flags on the question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/161545/show-flags). (The link is for Drupal Answer's moderators or Community Coordinators.)

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: The downvotes in the user tab take a while to clear; they'll be gone with the next reputation recalc.

Comment: In that case, I would expect the question's score to reflect that too. Yet, when a post I down-vote is deleted, I get back the reputation a way quicker than this.

Comment: A post deletion is a different kind of action than a flag invalidation, though. They happen more often, for one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is no rep recalc now.

Comment: The handling of the automatic downvotes resulting from spam and R/A flags was somewhat-recently changed. In the past, when a spam/R/A flag was declined, the downvote was not immediately removed, but the question was scheduled for a score recalculation, which would occur within 12 hours. A recalculation could be forced by adding an upvote or downvote, or requesting the score breakdown (i.e., clicking on the post score). *Now*, the post score is immediately recalculated when spam/R/A flags are declined.

Comment: As a result of this relatively recent change to the handling of the automatic downvotes from spam/R/A flags when the flags are declined, this question should be marked [tag:status-completed]. IIRC, there's at least one post on MSE or MSO describing the change. If it's on MSE, then this could, alternately, be closed as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Makyen That would explain what I noticed: Since I checked 7 hours after declining the spam flags, the recalculation did not happen, yet.